# Extra output on barcode scanning

Tags: ubuntu, barcode-scanner

I have a CipherLab 1000 scanner.
It seems as if the scan-result has a prefix? When I scan an ISBN 9788799412143, it gives this output: M139788799412143. 
Another book has this barcode at the back: 3249674930. When I scan it, the result is A103249674930.

Any ideas what's wrong? - And how it can be corrected?

David

Comment: You seem to have lost your account browser cookie, and are unable to *comment* on others' answers to your question. Super User is not a discussion forum, so please don't add "answers" that don't actually answer the question but only comment on others' posts. I converted your earlier answer to a comment, but please consider registering on the site.

Answer (score 1):

Barcodes come in different format's. The scanner is likely set for the wrong format. If you have the manual, find the page with a number of barcodes that will change the setting's of your scanner when you scan them, and then try each of the formatting options. This can also come in the form of a poster. We have a poster sitting on our back wall that we use to make sure scanners are set up correctly.

Comment: Strange... I can see your point, but when it scans the correct code/numbers, and then add a 'M13' or 'A10' prefix, is it then a wrong format? I'll look further into it... Thanks a lot!